# Facebook Javascript SDK Issue

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I am implementing Facebook javascript SDK on my site. I have a few issues with it.

First of all there are two instantiations of code on one page. One is a login button and other is the comment box. Now if i sign-In from the login button the commentBox does not update until the page is refreshed. What i want is that both of the widgets should update if one signs-In from any of them.

The second issue is with the login Button. I have implemented a onlogin function in it. What it is doing is that it calls the onlogin function even if i cancel to login when the login dialog appears after clicking the FAcebook login button.

If any one of you wants to visit the page. Here it is http://bit.ly/lIMjAf

Comment: These are good questions. I have the same issues. Have you found any resolution?